# Selecting a part of an image in matplotlib

Tags: python, image-processing, matplotlib

[image]

This is a binary image as displayed by matplotlib's imshow function. I want to create a new image which contains only a portion of the image above. Specifically, I want to select the range 150-180 on the horizontal axis. What's a simple way to achieve this?

Apologies if its obvious, I'm new to images so I haven't wrapped my head around them.

Comment: Your image is just a binary 2D array. Something like this should work: `cutout = img[150:180, :]`

Comment: @Paul for a horizontal selection you would need `img[:, 150:180]`. Apart that is probably the only valid answer one can give; would you like to write an answer which can be accepted such that the question can be marked as solved.

Comment: actually, although I totally agree that slicing the array is the best approach, this could also be what the OP is after: `ax.set_ylim((180,150))`